# What is the exact purpose of Yog Nidra?

Tags: scripture, yoga, yog-nidra

I would like to understand the exact purpose of Yog Nidra? Plus where is it stated in our scriptures? Are there any specific techniques stated in the scriptures for it?

Answer (score 3):

On a technique-research level, have a look at Makarand Gopal Newalkar’s [study on the Yoga Sutras](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/handle/10603/218748). He dedicates a section on the Yoganidra technique, where he positions the concept between the third and fourth state of consciousness (Turiya).

To illustrate, [here is the relevant section](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-sutras-study/d/doc628856.html):

> Patañjali says that there is absence of experience during deep sleep. However, the puruṣa who is the experiencer (seer) is still awake even during the sleep and it is possible to cognize this puruṣa during deep sleep. **This state, which is a borderline state of consciousness between suṣupti (deep sleep) and turīya (super consciousness) is termed as yoganidrā** by Svāmī Satyānanda Sarasvatī, the Founder of Bihar School of Yoga and the inventor of yoganidrā practice.

One who practices techniques associated with Yoganidra, "transcends the three initial states of awareness, entering into fourth unitive state beyond individual consciousness". The linked page contains elaborate details on techniques.

On a more formal/technical level, the term *yoganidrā* is defined in the Brahmsaṃhitā as "mystic slumber":

> The word yogamāyā (pastime potency) or yoga-nidrā (mystic slumber) should be understood to mean the natural or inherent illumination of the transcendental potency. However, its shadow, the illusory potency, is by nature inert and full of darkness.
>
> [source](https://books.google.nl/books?id=GbNN9N1T55cC&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125)

Yoganidrā is also mentioned as a synonym of Yogamāyā in the Bhāgavatapurāṇa (10.2.15) and commentary:

> The word yoga-nidrā is significant. When one is spiritually reconnected through self-realization, one regards his material life as having been like a dream.
> [...]
> The stage of self-realization is called yoga-nidrā. All material activities appear to be a dream when one is spiritually awakened. Thus yoga-nidrā may be explained to be Yogamāyā.
>
> [source](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/2/15/)

The Manthānabhairava-tantra (Kumārikākhaṇḍa chapter 13) defines yoganidrā as "Yogic sleep"

> Thus, by the constant practice of the means (karaṇa) (i.e. mantra), (the adept experiences) Yogic sleep (yoganidrā) which, stainless as pure crystal, is consciousness in which Māyā has been destroyed.
>
> [Source](https://books.google.nl/books?id=2DhazgEACAAJ&redir_esc=y)

Jayaratha refers to yoganidrā as the "fourth" of the five phases/states/signs of attainment:

> The yogi falls into a yogic sleep (yoganidrā) when the residual traces of these false notions dissolve away into consciousness. This is because although his connection with the body, senses and mind has been severed, he is not yet capable of grasping his own true, independent consciousness.

These five stages end with the state of ‘Great Pervasion’:—"As these traces decrease the yogi's realisation of his true identity becomes stable and he finally experiences the state of ‘Great Pervasion’ which is the condition of his authentic universal and transcendental nature."